# Final URDF+XACRO result

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have a model in URDF that I'm debugging it contains a few XACRO code and I would like to see the final result once the XACRO code has been evaluated, to be sure that the result is right.

How can I see that?

Cheers,
Germán

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88436/final-urdf+xacro-result/) by [gecastro](https://answers.ros.org/users/7526/gecastro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is the same question you are asking:

http://answers.ros.org/question/10401/how-to-convert-xacro-file-to-urdf-file/

Also the answer to your question appears to be in the xacro tutorials page:

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File#Using_Xacro

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0